# Header files, foward declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I was codding my project and i have come across this problem.
I have 2 header, each one with a class, that needs the other, as you can see below.

I thought that this was just needed the use of foward declaration, but still doesnt work.
Im out of Ideas.

Looking for Help :D

Headers , Main , and compiler erros listed bellow:

Header 1

```
#ifndef OBJ2_H
#define OBJ2_H
#include "obj1.h"
class obj1;

class obj2{
public:
    obj1 e;
};

#endif // OBJ2_H
```

Header 2

```
#ifndef OBJ1_H
#define OBJ1_H
#include "obj2.h"
class obj2;

class obj1
{
    obj2 e;
};

#endif // OBJ1_H
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "obj1.h"
#include "obj2.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    obj1 class1;
    obj2 class2;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

- include\obj2.h|8|error: field 'e' has incomplete type 'obj1'|
- include\obj1.h|8|error: field 'e' has incomplete type 'obj2'|

Comment: Declarations of *objects*, of *instance* need the full definition of the class or structure. You can bypass it by using pointers or references. Or by modifying your design so you don't have the circular dependency.

Comment: If every `obj1` has an `obj2` inside it, and vice versa, how big do you expect `obj1` to be?

Comment: no offense, but neither `obj1` nor `obj2` make any sense as you wrote it. If it was possible what you wrote they both would use infinite amount of memory (sorry for the spoiler)

Comment: btw there is nothing that would require you to write such classes, so you need to fix your design, not try to force it somehow

Comment: If you explained why this circular dependency is needed we might be able to suggest an alternative design. Circular dependencies hint to bad code design

Comment: ya, this was a stupid question , i just miss interpretae my problem , any ways thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this situation circular dependy make no sence. But if you remove it, problem with declarations would still be present. After you write a forward declaration, your original declaration from the header file is being **redeclared**.
Actually, forward declarations are used to **avoid including** file into another header. So you just need to write `class obj1;` before declaring obj2 and include obj1.hpp in obj2 source file (.cpp).
Still, forward declaration works only if you use those objects by reference or a pointer. In your code

```
class obj1
{
    obj2 e;
};
```

obj2 is composed by value, so it wouldn't compile with forward declaration. You need to remove it and leave only header inclusion.

P.S. sorry for 'declaration' word which appears too often